# When I try to deploy website, I get a blank page

Tags: deployment

I have a problem with deploying a website on git hub and Namecheap. On my local machine, it is working fine, but when I deploy it, I get a blank page.

This is the code: https://github.com/draftt4/Dev-It-house.git.

I don't see any errors in the console. I checked all the routes and all the links.